# Support vector machine, Lagrangian multipliers

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, machine-learning, data-analysis

I have equation of hyperplane which is:

$$0.83x+0.33y-3.52=0$$
Support vectors are :

First class: $(3.5,4.25),(4,3),(4.5,1.75)$

Second Class: $(2,2),(2.5,0.75)$

I want to find the Lagrangian multipliers.
How do I proceed.

Comment: That's not a hyperplane - it's a line.

Comment: @GFauxPas yes its linear support